# Trouble printing an array using Bluej

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

I'm trying to print a file which is separated lines of integers and I want to print the values after loading into an Array, so that I can process and printout the min, max, mean, median, etc.

Here is my code below, but it only prints out `2000`:

```
   String txt = UIFileChooser.open();
    this.data = new int[2000];
    int count = 0;
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(txt));
        while (scan.hasNextInt() && count<data.length){
            this.data[count] = scan.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
        scan.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {UI.println("Error");
    }
     {UI.printf("Count:  %d\n", this.data.length);
    }
```

Comment: You're printing the length of the array, which you define as 2000 in the line `this.data = new int[2000];` Are you trying to print out the values inside the array instead, or the number of values?

Comment: yes im trying to print out the values inside the array in a length but i hardly can't to work it out as i always get "2000" or terminal error

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting 2000 as your output every time is because you are only printing out the entire length of the array, which you define as 2000 in the line `this.data = new int[2000];`. To print out the number of values in the array, the simplest way would just be to use `count`, because it already holds that number. To print out all the values in the array, simply loop through the array up to the last value, printing each one. Code examples are below:

```
String txt = UIFileChooser.open();
this.data = new int[2000];
int count = 0;
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(txt));
    while (scan.hasNextInt() && count < data.length){
        this.data[count] = scan.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
    scan.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    UI.println("Error");
}

// this line will print the length of the array,
// which will always be 2000 because of line 2
UI.printf("Count:  %d\n", this.data.length);

// this line will print how many values are in the array
UI.printf("Values in array: %d\n", count);

// now to print out all the values in the array
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    UI.printf("Value: %d\n", this.data[i]);
}

// you can use the length of the array to loop as well
// but if count < this.data.length, then everything
// after the final value will be all 0s
for (int i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
    UI.printf("Value: %d\n", this.data[i]);
}
```

Comment: what if i still used this.data.length in printf but data.length as count is that possible? i mean using data.length to scan throughtout the data line by line like as a count because apperently UI.printf("Total size:  %d\n", this.data.length); is private as i cant change "university code". count works perfectly fine.

Comment: I edited my answer for what I think you are asking in your comment. You can use the length of the array in the loop instead of count, but if there aren't 2000 numbers in the file you read in, then everything after those numbers will be all 0s